# import from S3 fails due to question mark

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamoDB table having "author" as partition key and "title" as sort key.

One of the records has a question mark ? in it's title.
If I export the table to S3 and then import it back, it fails.

Are there any other special characters like question mark that will make it difficult to import from S3?

---

Update:

The table mentioned above is "poemGroup". I have another table called "poems". (Partition key: author (String) and Sort key: title (String). The title is same as title column in poemGroup table (foreign key in SQL dialect).  My android app developed in dart, does not display the contents if there is a question mark in the title column. It is possible that the bug is in my source code. https://github.com/ayush290104/MarathiPoet

I just need to confirm that there is no issue from dynamoDB side.

Comment: AFAIK only conventional characters are allowed. [Naming conventions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucketnamingrules.html)

Comment: DynamoDB table has "title" column that has a record, for e.g. "what is your name?" (without quotes) No problem in exporting the file to S3,  But can't import. That's the problem.

Comment: Ok, only when importing. Very strange...

Comment: Share the exception you are getting, and the sample item, then we can help.

Comment: Please also share the path you choose to import.

Comment: You are correct. May be I selected wrong compression type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you specify the correct path for import, ending at `data/`:

`s3://mybucket/myprefix/AWSDynamoDB/01696928512465-633b755c/data/`

Make sure you select:

`Import compression type = GZIP`

---

Here is my test:

#### My item:

```
{
 "PK": "Hello?",
 "SK": "World ?"
}
```

#### My Export

[image]

#### My Import

[image]

#### My item in the new table

```
{
 "PK": "Hello?",
 "SK": "World ?"
}
```

Comment: Question updated. The question mark (?) in title column made it difficult to be used in my android app. This is obviously dart issue and nothing to do with dynamoDB. But adding that info for record purpose.